# Google Sheets: Textjoin from another sheet not working

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula, textjoin

Working with the Base and Data tabs from this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsSWQ_48VrcTU3pXGeJ_1syluKPVeVRune39UA9I3x4/edit?usp=sharing

Expected result is textjoin of all colors matching SKU separated by comma in column C on Base tab.
Expected result shows in Column D, done manually.

All formulas i've tried either put everything in one cell (C2), gives an N/A error(C4), just pulls the first result (C5) or it is just completely blank.

Please help?  If you cannot, then thank you for reading anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I did it on a new [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsSWQ_48VrcTU3pXGeJ_1syluKPVeVRune39UA9I3x4/edit#gid=1286146791&range=A1) on the Spreadsheet that i took the liberty to create (hope it's ok)

For getting the colors I used **QUERY**: so it came out as `QUERY(Data!B:G,"select G where B = '"&A2&"'"`. After that I just fed that to your **JOINTEXT** formula

Comment: Looks like I would just copy that formula down then, instead of one formula to populate all of it?  I'm fine with that, thank you!  Huge help!

Comment: Maybe there's a way to make it one formula for all the cells. If you want I could try to make it.

Comment: @FledglingSysadmin Try to avoid the "i" word, even if applied to yourself. Your comment is harmless and only scolding yourself, but that word tends to trigger reactions, which then need to be caught in time to not hurt you. Also, you do not need to be that harsh with yourself. Making mistakes and learning from them is highly professional. People who are convinced that they never make mistakes .... them I do not trust.

Comment: Understood, poor joke on my part.